# Creating a simple header for website - why can't I get the img to float all the way right?

Tags: css, xhtml

I am making a very simple blog for my PHP project, but am having a simple problem. I can't get the image for my header to float all the way right. 
I have a banner with some text on the left, I have a 1px slice repeating across the width of whatever resolution may be chosen (ensuring the banner fills any screen).  I would like the image to always render on the right edge of the screen, again, independent of screen resolution. But it is coming in at a fixed position. Here is what I have written:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="banner" title="Prairie"/>
    <img class="right_image" src="images/banner_right_image.jpg" alt="elavator" title="prairie elevator"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: url(images/banner_right.jpg) repeat-x;
    z-index: 1;
}
#header.right_image {
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

What is the issue here?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You generally don't want `position: fixed` on everything.

Comment: I can appreciate that, but I want the banner to show while scrolling down the page. I thought that was the only way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should separate `#header.right_image` so that it is `#header .right_image`

Also remove `position: fixed` from `#header.right_image`

This works:

```css
#header .right_image {
    float: right;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FTBWU/

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason.  Bloody new people, eh? Such a simple thing. Damn.

Comment: No problem @mrwienerdog!  It usually is the simplest thing.  Last week I spent two hours trying to fix a problem before I realized I was missing an `=` !

Answer (score 1):

A link to your site would help!

I always throw at the top of my header:

```
 * { margin:0; padding:0}
```

You probably have padding or margins inherintly applied to your html or body tags depending on what browser you're using.  Try that - and the is there a URL I can see the whole thing at?

Comment: On the contrary, oftentimes an OP will supply only a link and not the relevant markup and styles. Although it would help, for the question's durability, providing the relevant question markup and style should be sufficient in most cases. `:)`

Comment: I was actually taught to always have that as my first line of css, so it is there. I would give a link, but I only have the page(s) local at the moment. Also, I always appreciate reading what everyone has to say, it's a great way for me to learn. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well the float works with a fixed positioned element. Maybe try something like this for your image?

```css
#header .right_image {
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: From what I read at W3, float works with all positions except absolute. Thanks!